# How can I use Unix to rename all html files by their titles?

Tags: sed

As in, rename all HTML files in a directory by the text contained in TEXT?

Could a combination of grep, sed, and mv work?

For example, I have a file contained 1.html. The title of 1.html is contained in the HTML file as TEXT (it is contained within the title tags TEXT. I would like to rename 1.html to TEXT.html

If a file is named as 5.html, and the title of 5.html is TEST2, then I want to rename 5.html to TEST2.html.

Comment: You should provide more information, like input, expected output.

Comment: Define "title". Do you mean the part of the web page contained inside the `<title>` tags?

Comment: yes. i'll update it.

Comment: When you say 'TEXT', do you mean the HTML `<title/>` element? In other words, do you want to rename all of the HTML files such that each file has the name of its `<title/>` element?

Comment: Yes - that's what I want to do.

Comment: This has already been answered on StackOverflow - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389631/renaming-html-files-using-title-tags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for file in *.html ; do 
    name="$(sed -n '/<title>/{s=[^>]*title>==;s=</title.*==;s=[^0-9A-Za-z-_]=_=g;p;q}' "$file")"
    if [ -f "$name" ]; then
       [ -f "${name}_$file" ] || mv -f "$file" "${name}_$file"
    else
       mv -v "$file" "${name}.html"
    fi
done
```

`sed` explanation:

```
    /<title>/ -- finds the string with <title> and 
                 applies a group of commands to it
    {}        -- a group of commands
    s=[^>]*title>== -- removes everything before <title> including tag
    s=</title.*==   -- removes everything after </title> including tag
    s=[^0-9A-Za-z-_]=_=g -- substitute all non alphabet/num characters to _  
    p -- print the output
    q -- exit as there is no need to process rest of the file
```

ps. put `echo` before every `mv` to run in dry mode and verify everything looks fine.

pps. also sed construction expects, that fdjskjfls is on the one line and doesn't have any tags before on the same line.

Comment: I think your definition of "very clear" is a bit permissive :)

Comment: Awesome - thanks! Just curious - what would happen if the file contained multiple <title></title> tags? Also, what would happen if multiple files contained the same title?

Comment: @InquilineKea in case with multiple titles the first one will be used. In case with the same titles currently it files will be overwritten.

Comment: @InquilineKea I modified the loop to also check if file already exists and if yes it will try to add existing filename to the title. Also a bit more detailed sed explanation is added.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a simpler approach, assuming you have GNU `grep`:

```
for f in *.html ; do 
    mv -v "$f" "$(grep -oP '<title>\K.+?</title>' $f | sed 's#</title>##').html"
done
```

Comment: For macOS users: `-P` is not supported on the native grep. Install GNU Grep with e.g. Homebrew. Otherwise, this worked perfectly, cheers.